# vscode simple-browser connect through tunnel

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Should it be supported to connect through remote tunnels and web page like here on my device?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arK27.png)

Its running lighttpd and page can be displayed with my lan ip instead of tunnel address but it would be nice to admin this device trought the allready excisting tunnel.